Clean Subdivision Topology using Inset
Good evening!
I've been stuck with this issue for about 1 week now and that's why I'm seeking help from you guys.
My issue is with the control loops after making the inset. The control loops go around the whole object creating a bunch of extra edges that are not necessary and makes the topology really messy.
My questions for you:

Is it possible to restrain the edge loop from going around the whole object e.g. the control loops on the side for the middle "bar" going around both side "pillars" as well [Picture1].




How should I tackle this issue, or more like in which order should I add the detail and make the control loops? As of now I have made the whole structure, made the control loops for the structure and after that I have started making the "bars" going across, but adding control loops for the "bar" is a pain as it adds control loops around the rest of the structure as well.

How do I make this a smart way considering the subdivision surface modifier?



Or is it really to just add all control loops and manually dissolve them to remove unnecessary edge loops?
Disclaimer: I've been working with Blender for about 3-4 weeks now and I want to learn clean topology now because I believe I will thank myself later for that. I've been stuck with this longer that I should and I'm starting to lose my hair as I don't seem to figure it out by myself...
Thank you and all the best to all of you!
Reference what I want to achieve.


What kind of subdivision surface do you want to add (small bevel of edges VS totally rounded object) ? It would help people to know, as topology depends on it. Could you add an example ? All the best to you as well.

Hi! That's a good point. I would like to have sharp edges e.g. keep the same "cubic" shape as in the picture. Only subdivision surface I know is SubD level 3 with the normal control loops.
As I'm so new to this still it's difficult for me to even ask the questions...

Do you have any reference/image/example about what you are trying to achieve ? I'm guessing you don't want your edges to be totally sharp, do you ?

I added a reference picture to the post of the final product I would like to achieve. In the reference the bars across are rounded, but I would like to have them more square like, where the inset area (Picture 3) has welded looking edges. So you're right, that I don't want completely sharp edges! :)

I would do this topology, yours is about the same actually:


Thank you moonboots for your insight, greatly appreciated!
Did you use bevel on the left side corner for the larger pillar?

I don't remember but yes it's the same as a bevel, I could have used 2 segments instead of one

Alright, thanks!
I'll try to finish the object during this week and post the result to get advice on how the topology can be improved further!
